# get-content powershell commandlet is not returning

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to get the contents of a file as hex in Powershell, and I am using the following:

```
get-content -encoding byte $fullFilePath | %{"{0:X2}" -f $_} | %{$hex = $hex + $_}
```

When I run this script, I do not get an error, but it does not return, it just hangs.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How big is the file in `$fullFilePath`?  You can skip the second `ForEach-Object` as well: `Get-Content $fullFilePath -Encoding Byte |  %{ $hex += "{0:X2}" -f $_ }` -- tested with a few smaller files and `$hex` is populated very quickly. Testing with a 43MB PDF and it's been running for over two minutes.

Comment: Only 67k.  I did wait longer, and it returned. Thanks for the help.  PLEASE post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string concatenation is going to be a serious performance drag.  I'd switch to using a stringbuilder:

```
$hex = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

get-content -encoding byte $fullFilePath | 
%{"{0:X2}" -f $_} | %{$hex.Append($_) > $null}

$hex = $hex.ToString()
```

Testing with a 125KB file dropped the run time from 58 seconds to 12 after switching from concatenation to using the stringbuilder.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com), it has a `Format-Hex` command (alias fhex) e.g.:

```
get-content -encoding byte $fullFilePath | fhex
```